# Mongo Template : Modifying Match Operation dynamically

Tags: mongotemplate

I have defined my match operation in mongo template as below.

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("workflow_stage_current_assignee").ne(null)
            .andOperator(new Criteria("CreatedDate").gte(new Date(fromDate.getTimeInMillis()))
            .andOperator(new Criteria("CreatedDate").lte(new Date(toDate.getTimeInMillis())))));
```

Everything is fine until this. However I can not modify this match operation using the reference `match` I have created. I was looking for List kind of functionality where in I could add multiple criteria clauses as and when they are needed to an already created reference. Something on the lines `match.add(new Criteria)`

However `MatchOperation` currently does not support any methods which would provide this functionality. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Criteria` is where you add new criteria, which is backed by list.

Use static `Criteria where(String key)` method to create a initialize criteria object.

Something like

```
Criteria criteria = where("key1").is("value1");
```

Add more criteria's

```
criteria.and("key2").is("value2");
```

Create implicit [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#examples) criteria and chain to existing criteria chain.

```
criteria.and(where("key3).gt(value3).lte(value4))
```

When you are done, just pass it to match operation.

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);
```

Comment: The answer helped. Except a small change in code as below.


`Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("key1").is("value1")`